# Is Face ID mandatory?

Tags: iphone, face-id

As a long time Android user I wanted to give Apple a shot and got myself an iPhone 8 a few years ago. While I never regretted switching systems, I'm currently looking for a smartphone with a better resolution and camera.

The concerns I have with the modern phones is the authentication method. Face ID to be exact. Since day one I always made sure to cover up the front camera. I never had the need to use it, and to be honest, I feel safer that way.

Now regarding the iPhone 13 or 14. Will it be possible for me to log in and authenticate myself without Face ID? From what I've read online it seems to me it won't be possible. But I thought it might be better to get confirmation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FaceID does not use the front camera, it is a different system.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208108

That being said, no, it is not mandatory.

Comment: "*If you choose to enroll in Face ID, you can control how it's used* **or disable it at any time**". That seems acceptable, even though I'll miss having Touch ID.

Comment: @Seir Regarding safety. Using Face ID makes a decent password (mine is 12 characters) manageable.  Without Face ID you would be tempted to use a short password (or PIN) which reduces the phone security and hence your safety.